# Помогите определить элемент последовательности

Tags: алгоритм

По условию задачи дано значение первого элемента последовательности равное N. Остальные элементы последовательности находятся по формуле:

```
arr [i] = (arr [i-1] + arr[i+1])/2 - 1
```

Как найти второй и последующие элементы? Не могу понять как это сделать имея только первый элемент.

Comment: какая-то у вас странная рекуррентная формула - для того чтобы найти второй элемент надо знать первый и третьий элементы и т.д.

Comment: Ну, ваша формула переписывается как `a[i+1] = a[i-1]-2-2*a[i]`, но в любом случае нужно знать **ДВА** начальных значения.

Comment: в том то и дело! если бы было известо два элемента - я бы не спрашивал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опустим момент, что первый элемент не может быть вычислен, потому, что перед ним больше нет элементов. Он нам дан, это `N`. Кроме того, видно, что третий элемент зависит как от первого так и от второго. Возьмем за второй элемент любое число, какое нам больше нравится, от него ничего не зависит. Пусть это будет `X`. Тогда третий элемент мы можем вычислить по формуле `2X+2-N`. В итоге мы можем сгененрировать бесконечно много верных последовательностей, беря разные 2-е элементы.

Comment: окей, допустим первый элемент 15. второй выбираем 13 - тогда (arr [0] + arr [2]) / 2 должно равняться 14, а это значит, что 3 элемент == 13. тоесть это невозможно, так как он должен быть меньше второго.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вы как то не так посчитали. `15 - 2*13 - 2 = -13` третий элемент -13, а не +13

Comment: это ты как-то неправильно условие прочитал: второй элемент на 1 меньше, чем среднее от первого и второго элемента

Comment: и третьего* - ошибся малость

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Смотрите, мы вычислили ряд 15, 13, -13. Давайте проверим второй элемент (при счете с 1, который 13), он должен быть `(arr[0]-arr[2])/1-1` считаем `(15 - (-13)) / 2 - 1  =  (15 + 13)/2 -1  = 28/2 - 1 =  13` что по вашему не так с нашим рядом ?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch И кстати, почему вы говорите, что второй элемент на 1 меньше чем _среднее_ от 1 и третьего. Вы же в вопросе написали `(arr [i-1] - arr[i+1])/2` - это не среднее, это половина от разности двух элементов, если бы было среднее, была бы сумма ..

Comment: блин, я сразу не заметил! Там не минус должен быть, а плюс - опечатка.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch тогда воспользуйтесь школьными знаниями по математике, и из вашего уравнения для элемента в середине сделайте уравнение для определения 3го элемента по первым 2м

Comment: это я и сделал в том комменте, где выбрал число 13 - условие в этом случае не выполняется, так как 3 элемент = 2 элементу - а это не может быть

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Почему этого не может быть ? ведь в ряде 15,13,13 средний элемент равен среднему между соседями минус 1 ?

Comment: Ага. Если ты подумал, что 4 элемент может быть 15 - то нет, это убывающая последовательность.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А где сказано, что она должна быть возрастающей или убывающей ? Только не говорите, что и это вы забыли указать в условиях задачи. править вопрос столько раз просто не красиво. вам отвечают исходя из тех условий задачи, которые вы поставили ! Ну если вам нужна какая то конкретная последовательность, от думаю вам стоит немного подбирать подходящее второе число или вывести формулу, которая даст примерный диапазон таких чисел

Comment: Да, согласен, немного некрасиво получилось: я просто не учел, что при таких условиях последовательность может возрастать...